# How to evaluate $\int { \frac { dx }{ { 2x }^{ 4 }+{ 2x }^{ 2 }+1 } }$?

Tags: integration

How to integrate something like 
$\int { \frac { dx }{ { 2x }^{ 4 }+{ 2x }^{ 2 }+1 }  }$
I know the method of partial fractions.

But what if the denominator is not factorizeable like the one in the question?

Comment: it's a bicuadratic, you should be able to use a factorization and use partial fractions.

Comment: @3d0 I'm asking when its not factorizable!

Comment: show an example then Sanchayan.

Comment: The roots are $\pm\sqrt{\frac{-b\pm \sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}}$.

Comment: It's always factorizable, you just have to factorize it in the complex numbers sometimes.

Comment: Sorry, I answered before you made the edit. Still you could force a little the answer using complex factorization.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I got what you mean.But now I need an example to understand that :-P.I never integrated anything involving complex numbers...

Answer (score 6):

A partial partial fraction approach:

$$\frac{1}{ax^4+bx^2+c} = \frac{1}{a}\left(\frac{A_1}{x^2-r_1} + \frac{A_2}{x^2-r_2}\right)$$

where $r_1,r_2$ are the (possibly complex) roots of $au^2+bu+c=0$.

(You'll have to take care if $r_1=r_2$.)

Solve for $A_1,A_2$, and then use techniques know for integrating $\int \frac{dx}{x^2-r_i}$.

Ultimately, you need to know how to compute: $\log(x-(u+vi))$. Here, we get:

$$\log(x-(u+vi)) = \log(\sqrt{(x-u)^2+v^2})+i\theta$$ there $\tan\theta = \frac{v}{x-u}$. The complex parts will cancel out, so $\theta$ is irrelevant.

Comment: But how to handle if there are complex roots of the equation.It would be helpful if you can give an illustration.

Comment: Then start out with a specific example. @SanchayanDutta Don't ask a general question if you don't want a general answer.

Comment: @SanchayanDutta: Complex roots change nothing. Partial fractions work the same regardless, just looks a little messier. In theory, no difference. For example: $$\frac1{x^2+1}=\frac{i/2}{x+i} - \frac{i/2}{x-i}$$

Comment: The real problem is repeated roots. Well, not a problem, just a special case.

Comment: @MPW well well! I got it now :-)!thanks

Comment: You need to use that log(a + b i) = 1/2 log(a^2 + b^2) + i arctan(b/a)

Answer (score 2):

First pull out any constant coefficient of $x^4$ to get a monic polynomial.

In $$ x^4 + B x^2 + C  $$ with $$ B^2 - 4 C < 0,  $$ so that $C > 0,$ we get
$$ x^4 + B x^2 + C = (x^2 + \lambda x + \sqrt C)  (x^2 - \lambda x + \sqrt C),  $$
where
$$ \lambda = \sqrt {2 \sqrt C - B}  $$
is also real.

***The original problem was edited*** to $2 x^4 + 2 x^2 + 1 = 2 \left(x^4 + x^2 + \frac{1}{2} \right);$

$$ x^4 + x^2 + \frac{1}{2} = \left(x^2 + \sqrt{\sqrt 2 - 1} \; x +  \frac{1}{\sqrt 2} \right)  \left(x^2 -  \sqrt{\sqrt 2 - 1} \; x + \frac{1}{\sqrt 2} \right)   $$

Comment: Why the downvote? (+1) by me.